# Xorg Issues Ubuntu 12.04 - Freezing

Tags: 12.04, xorg

I'm getting random freezing issues on my PC running 12.04 (Core i5 3450 w/ integrated graphics) and haven't been able to pinpoint the exact cause of the problem. However I have been getting  "Sorry, Ubuntu 12.04 has experienced an internal error" messages regarding "Xorg".

Here's a screenshot of the error window: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6rW2.png

This is on a clean install of Ubuntu as well. One thing I noticed is these issues start happening the moment I connect my PC to the Internet and attempt to install updates which always results in an error.

Here's a screenshot of the update manager error:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cuVt.png

Any ideas on what could be causing this issue?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 1):

"random freeze" - could be anything, you need to follow the freeze troubleshooting guide in order to see what error number your GPU is getting.

"error window" - that actually shows a crash not a freeze.  For crashes you need the backtrace.  unfortunately you didn't expand it in your dialog screenshot so it's anyone's guess what's wrong.

"update manager error" - it looks to me like your network connection has failed.  mx.archive.ubuntu.com responds fine for me.

Comment: Is there a way for me to save the error report and post it here? Also this PC has a stable network connection but for some reason always gets stuck on those Release.gpg files. The rest appear to download fine. I even tried downloading them via terminal and got the same error.

Comment: There is, but this isn't the place to post it.  There's a plethora of troubleshooting documents on how to solve X crash and GPU freeze issues.